# How to call a method from another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

Suppose we have a class, and in this class there is a method called `OnRec()`. I want to call another class's method from within `OnRec()`.

I would like to use something like `Listener`, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass {
    // ...

    public void OnRec() {
        // Here I want to call a method in a class in another package 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Could someone please explain how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have your .jar library imported in your project, you simply import your class that you need.

---

Case example, class named `RandomClass` contains method `getRandomValue`.

You simply import the class that has the `RandomClass` depending on the `package`.

Case example, class `com.testlibrary.main` contains `RandomClass.java`

In our class we simply import the class:

> import com.testlibrary.main

And we are then allowed to used it's methods such as `RandomClass#getRandomValue`

Comment: how to add Listener to this method?